# Symfony3 - multiple Entity Managers and Connections

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I tried to create an entity from a table in a pre-existing database :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle yml --filter="someTable"
```

But a message showed up stating :

> Table someTable has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse 
>   engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.

I checked, and in the DB, there were some tables without any PK (and I cannot change that).
So I read this  page : http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html
... and tried this solution on github : 
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/441

My config.yml is like this :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
            forMapping:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                schema_filter: someTable

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/config
            forMapping:
                connection: forMapping
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/config
```

But when I try :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --em=forMapping --filter="someTable" AppBundle yml
```

I get :

> [InvalidArgumentException] Doctrine ORM Manager named "forMapping" does not exist.

Emptied the cache, but nope. Any help appreciated.

MC

Comment: Remove the auto_mapping line.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I goofed on my previous answer.
How about you try the command like this instead:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "AppBundle" yml --em=forMapping --filter="someTable"
```

Does it make a difference? I see from a command line using the --help, it show in that order.

Comment: Interesting suggestion.  Given that the entities are generated by using the import command and given that the import command is not running then how exactly would you check these non-existent entities?  And why would there be annotations when using the yaml mapping option?

Comment: I just realized I goofed. Thanks for the hint @Cerad !

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Was due to the "auto_mapping". Correct sequence seems to be :

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        auto_mapping: true
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                    type: yml
                    dir: Resources/config
        # See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/441
        forMapping:
            connection: forMapping
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                    type: yml
                    dir: Resources/config
```

It works one step further to the next error message. When I try :

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "AppBundle" yml --em=forMapping

The following error message pops up :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>   Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Ok, let's see to this. The schema_filter was wrong. Correct code is :

```
schema_filter: ~^spip_rubriques$~
```

My entity has been correctly generated. I thank you all for your help.

MC

Comment: So the order of the `doctrine:mapping:import` options did matter? Can you click the up triangle on my answer to indicate I help (in some way)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your "forMapping" is not correct in

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        #problem here
        forMapping:
```

Try to find out what is going wrong here